# Estimate of the logarithmic derivative of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: analytic-number-theory

How I can achieve this result. If $\sigma > 1$
$$-\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(\sigma) \ll (\sigma -1 )^{-1}$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Zeta'[x] / Zeta[x] has negative values for all x > 1. WHen x goes to infinity, its limit is zero by negative values. The right hand side is always positive.

Comment: If i change the sign of $\zeta'/\zeta (\sigma)$?

Comment: Then, the problem is different : -Zeta'[x]/Zeta[x] is an decreasing function of x as well as 1/(x-1). Both functions are monotone and have an horizontal asymptote at y=0. if you compute a Taylor expansion around x=1, the first term is 1/(x-1) -EulerGamma + k (x-1), k being a positive constant (0.1875). I do not know how much this will help you. Let me know.

Comment: One thing I forgot : when x is large, Zeta[x] can be approximated by (1 + 2^(-x) + 3^(-x) + ..). Take the derivative; it leads to -Zeta'[x]/Zeta[x] close to Log(2)/(1+2^x). I think that this could help.